# update multiple rows of table in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to insert some data against each row with one submit button. So I included a table inside a form tag and implemented like this:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of list;let index = index>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="model[index]" id="{{item.id}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 <button type="submit">Proceed</button>
</form>
```

what I want is to insert data inside input tag against that 'item.id' on submit button but i am not able to retrieve 'id' with submit button. What I am getting is array of input values without i.e [75, 76] considering i have to update two rows. So how could i retrieve id's against each row or update data on each entry.

Comment: Your submit button is out of the for loop therefore you will not be able to get the indexs the way you have it.  Try to create submit  function for the form and in the submit function loop thru "model" for the indexes you want to update.

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  the onSubmit function will be able to access your "model" model.

Comment: If i will put submit button inside <tr> it will create submit button for each row and i dont want that. I want submit button to submit all entries at on time.

Comment: correct.... that is why I was saying put a submit function in the form and access the "model" from within the function and loop thru the "model" to get the indexes.

Comment: Check this plunker:   https://plnkr.co/edit/JZ94mTquGmRkq1Xmhgec?p=preview

Comment: @btinoco thanks it worked.

Comment: If that work please check my response as the right answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a submit function to your form and in the submit function access your "model" variable to get all the indexes of the fields.

```
class MyComponent{
    model:any;

    OnSubmit(){

        window.alert(JSON.stringify(model);

    }

}
```

Check my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/JZ94mTquGmRkq1Xmhgec?p=preview